# Increase the size of tableView Cell..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Is it possible to increase the size of particular cell in the TableView.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

By using this we can increase the size of the table cell for a tableView but it will increase all the tableCell size.

But I want to increase the height of first cell is up-to 130 and other cell are of height 100. Can any one suggest me the best way for doing this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make height value dependent on cell's position (indexPath), e.g. to make 1st cell higher then others do the following:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
         return 130.0f;

     return 100.0f;
}
```

*Note that with that code if you have several section then 1st cells in all sections will be higher then others.